# What does this conditional operator do?

Tags: python, syntax, conditional-operator

I'm not really sure how to interpret them and i'm still struggling to find out what they're exactly doing..

```
color = self.color2

color = self.fill1 if color == self.fill2 else self.fill2
```

what is this exactly saying?

Comment: That is not a list comprehension. It is more akin to a ternary conditional operator.

Comment: Isn't it readable as a line??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

> The expression x if C else y first evaluates the condition, C (not x); if C is true, x is evaluated and its value is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and its value is returned.

So, your specific example is equivalent to:

```
if color == self.fill2:
    color = self.fill1
else:
    color = self.fill2
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not list comprehension. It is sort of a syntactic sugar.
Ironically it is meant to improve readability.

It can be interpreted as:

```
if color == self.fill2:
    color = self.fill1
else:
    color = self.fill2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) See [PEP-308](http://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html).

So something like this

```
x = true_value if condition else false_value
```

It can also be written as

```
if condition:
    x = true_value
else:
    x = false_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it says exactly what it says: put the value of `self.fill1` into `color` variable if value of `color` equals to `self.fill1`, otherwise put `self.fill2`. It's called **ternary operator**, you can find more information about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#Python).